# facing issues whille installing npm ts loader and npm css loader

Tags: node.js, css-loader, ts-loader

I am getting all these warning while installing ts loader and css loader..

npm ts loader

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T420s:~$ npm install --save-dev ts-loader
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
/home/user
`-- ts-loader@2.1.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.
```

npm css loader

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T420s:~$ npm install --save-dev css-loader
    npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
    /home/user
    `-- css-loader@0.28.2 

    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/package.json'
    npm WARN user No description
    npm WARN user No repository field.
    npm WARN user No README data
    npm WARN user No license field.
```

can anyone tell me how i can fix this ?

Comment: npm doesn't find your _package.json_ file, seems you are not in your project folder, and it fail to save ts-loader as a dependency.

Comment: please help me understand how to use css-loader in bundling with webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you pass `--save-dev` parameter to npm when you install *ts-loader* and *css-loader* modules in a directory with no package.json in it.

If this is a new project, I suggest you to start by `npm init`, as it will create you a fresh package.json file for your project.

You can always install dependency globally if you needed it for more than one project:

```
npm install -g ts-loader css-loader
```

Others alert are not very important, but you can add a licence and a README file to get rid of it if you care.

Comment: installing command worked for me.. can you please also explain me how to use css loader in webpack

Comment: You should ask another question about that as I am not a webpack specialist